# SQL to Calculate Total Duration in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have duration field in my **redshift** table as defined as **varchar** field and the data is in the below formate (hours:minutes:seconds:microseconds):

Example:

| Duration |
| --- |
| 00:00:02.696000 |
| 00:04:04 |
| 00:01:04.127000 |
| 04:03:02.063000 |
| 00:03:08.300000 |
| 00:05:05 |
| 00:01:00.150000 |
| 32:01:03.200000 |

I would need find out the total duration. Some durations are more than 24 hours

Do we have any SQL that we can calculate the total duration in hours:minutes:seconds:microseconds ?

In above case the total is approx. -->  36:18:28
which is 36 hours and 18 minutes and 28 seconds and some micro seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is doable with SQL in Redshift.  The strings you have are castable to the INTERVAL data type - which is a valid intermediate data type but values cannot be stored to tables as this type.  Once cast these interval values can be summed.  Here's a simple test case from your data;

```
CREATE TABLE NEW_TEST 
(dur   VARCHAR(100)
);

INSERT INTO NEW_TEST
VALUES
('00:00:02.696000'),
('00:04:04'),
('00:01:04.127000'),
('04:03:02.063000'),
('00:03:08.300000'),
('00:05:05'),
('00:01:00.150000'),
('32:01:03.200000');

select sum(dur::interval) from NEW_TEST;
```

The final SQL select statement produces the result:

```
 1 day 12:18:29.536
```

Now this is the right answer but not in the format you want.  Unfortunately, the Redshift date/time formatting functions don't take intervals as an input so this will be a little manual.  This statement makes what you are looking for:

```
select extract(hour from sum(dur::interval)) || ':' || 
    extract(min from sum(dur::interval)) - extract(hour from sum(dur::interval)) * 60 || ':' ||
    extract(sec from sum(dur::interval)) - extract(min from sum(dur::interval)) * 60 || '.' ||
    extract(usec from sum(dur::interval)) - extract(sec from sum(dur::interval)) * 1000000 as duration
from new_test;
```

This SQL select statement produces the result:

```
36:18:29.536000
```

Does this meet your need?

Comment: Thanks - that works most of the part but just i have some data in this formate on the same table :  12.00:48:42.1660000 which is 12 days and 48 minutes and 42 seconds. can you update the sql to handle this scenario ? INSERT INTO NEW_TEST
VALUES
('00:00:02.696000'),
('00:04:04'),
('00:01:04.127000'),
('04:03:02.063000'),
('00:03:08.300000'),
('00:05:05'),
('00:01:00.150000'),
('12.00:48:42.1660000', 13.04:18:34.3400000
);